# Using the REST API to perform bulk payouts on behalf of our client

Tags: rest, api, paypal, oauth

I am a long paypal API user and am trying to use the new(er) REST API for my app. I have been pleased with the quality of the docs and API over our existing integration with paypal masspay, but I fear I have misunderstood the use of the REST API.

I have done at least a dozen other OAuth2 integrations with a lot of different services, and every one of them sets up a connection and gives us (the 3rd party app owner) a token, which lets us act on their behalf.

When I discovered the "My Apps" and REST API of paypal, saw it generated a client_id/secret, naturally I assumed I could create an app, and integrate it into my software, so that my clients can 'add' the app (initiating an oauth connection), and then I have a token that I can use to create payouts on their behalf. What led to the confusion, in retrospect, is that I was able to obtain a token, and then make SOME REST API calls (specifically, the identity calls, which give me info about my clients paypal account), but even if I added the following oauth scopes:

https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/.* https://uri.paypal.com/payments/payouts

I am getting permission denied whenever I try to initiate a payout, or use any API other than the identity calls.

So after further digging, I am coming to the conclusion that the REST API, and the whole 'apps' thing is simply for writing apps for your OWN account (except for identity), NOT for allowing my app to act on behalf of a 3rd party, as has been the case for every other oauth integration I have ever done.

Does this sound correct? Am I missing something that lets me identify what merchant I am acting on behalf of?

I'd really like to move off the masspay API as its very clunky. Please help!

Comment: Oh yeah, and Masspay is now deprecated: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/#mass-payments

So what is an app writer to do if they want to allow their client to perform bulk payouts??

Comment: actually you can use the open id code in the api , but first you have to exchange the auth code into a access token https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/lipp/UserConsentRedirect.php